# How to click on center of image in pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to click on the center of the image so what can I do I'm tired to click on the centre of the image in pyautogui

For Example for an image we need to write this:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
```

How Can I locate the center of the image?

Comment: can I found look like a picture in pyautogui not exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly find the center of the image using the built in [locateCenterOnScreen](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) method.

```
locateCenterOnScreen(image, grayscale=False)
```

Returns `(x, y)` coordinates of the center of the first found instance of the image on the screen. Raises `ImageNotFoundException` if not found on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

As codelt said, locateCenterOnScreen(image) will return x,y and this is the most efficient way.

For more flexibility, remember that locateOnScreen() will also take the *confidence* argument.  This allows you to be flexible about how *certain* you want it to be before it returns coordinates.  You can then run this through center() which will return the X,y coordinates.

For example, if pyautogui was having difficulty finding the image with high degrees of confidence but could find the image with lower confidence:

```
locateCenterOnScreen(image)
#returns None

locateOnScreen(image, confidence=0.7)
#returns box coordinates as it found the image at a lower confidence

pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image,confidence=0.7))
#returns center coordinates, exactly the same as locateCenterOnScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('neverbtn.png')
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

Comment: Hi Usman, thank you for your great code! Can you please explain your code and tell about how it helps? You may want to checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: yes sure, `locateCenterOnScreen('neverbtn.png')` this function return coordinates (x,y) from the center of the image, e.g. you have an image like this [image](https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*Saw33rYir4VjwaHkqvDO_g.png), pass (x,y) to click() function of pyautogui